# How to send notifications from a Controller (WebAPI) to SignalR Hub so the hub will broadcast it to the client

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, blazor, signalr

My architecture is set up in the following way:

1. a client side, where a SignalR Client is installed, is used to send and receive information directly to and from the SignalR Hub (NotificationService).
2. Additionally, a server, primarily a WebAPI, is employed to broadcast information to the SignalR Hub, which then distributes the information to the client. This server also has a SignalR Client installed.

Example of WebAPI to Hub Method:

```
    public async Task NotifyUpdates(Guid roomId)
    {
        try
        {

            await StartConnection();
            await hubConnection.SendAsync("OnNotifyUpdates", roomId);
            await CloseConnection();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { throw; }
    }
```

In a development environment, the architecture functions as intended, with no errors or disconnections. Conversely, when in a production environment, no data is received from the server (WebAPI) to the notificationService, and if it is, it immediately disconnects.

I am uncertain as to the connection between the server and the hub. Is the appropriate method of establishing such a connection via the SignalR client side package? I would be grateful for any advice on the subject.

Comment: Just for the record: you don't actually just throw in the catch block, do you?

Comment: I will add logger

Comment: First of all you would need a hubClass which should be inherited from `Hub` interface and here you should write your broadcusting method. On top of this, now you have to call your HubClass from your controller using `IHubContext<HubClass>` by passing through the constructor. Finally, any client who will be calling this controller would immediately receive  broadcusted message.